# How to import and run C-Sparql readyToPack in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, sparql, rdf

I want to start to implement a small project with c - SPARQL but I'm stuck right at the start.

How do I import the `readyToPack` project ([GitHub](https://github.com/streamreasoning/CSPARQL-ReadyToGoPack)) into Eclipse and run the project?

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, go to File -> Import -> Git -> Projects from Git -> Either download the project from Github and then use the local directory or use the clone URI.

After importing to Eclipse:
Since it's a maven project, go to Run configurations -> Maven Build -> Goal: clean install